# How to do peek operation in stack of array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, stack

```
int peek()
{
    if(top == -1)
    {
        printf("\n \t STACK UNDERFLOW");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        if(x != -1)
            printf("\n The top most element is %d",x);
        return x[top];
    }
}
```

My Peek Operation is not printing the correct output. The Output should be the topmost element in an array of stack, it prints random numbers. The Peek operation should print the topmost element in an array of stack inputted by the user.

For example:

```
----------------------------------------
         ARRAY OF STACK
----------------------------------------
 [1] PUSH
 [2] POP
 [3] PEEK
 [4] DISPLAY
 [5] EXIT
----------------------------------------
 Enter you Choice: 1
----------------------------------------
Enter element to add: Jennie
----------------------------------------
         ARRAY OF STACK
----------------------------------------
 [1] PUSH
 [2] POP
 [3] PEEK
 [4] DISPLAY
 [5] EXIT
----------------------------------------
 Enter you Choice: 1
----------------------------------------
Enter element to add: Lisa
----------------------------------------
         ARRAY OF STACK
----------------------------------------
 [1] PUSH
 [2] POP
 [3] PEEK
 [4] DISPLAY
 [5] EXIT
----------------------------------------
 Enter you Choice: 3

 The top most element is 4229504
```

The output should be "The topmost element is Lisa" How to correct this? I need to print the topmost element in the stack inputted by the user. I also get "Warning comparison between pointer and integer" as a warning in "if(x != -1)" in peek operation.

Comment: `if(x != -1)` - x is an array of chars, not an integer. You should compile with all warning enabled and the compiler will complain about this.

Comment: The compiler produces a number of warnings pointing out locations where there are serious issues in your code. [Fixing these would be a good place to start.](https://godbolt.org/z/Y367MvK83)

Comment: How to fix the Warning comparison between pointer and integer"??

Comment: There are many warnings currently ignored. They summarily resulted in unwanted output. You should pick up a good C programming book and never miss the compiler-generated warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stack, `a`, is an array of strings, and top is the current position:

```
char *peek() {
    if(top == -1) {
        printf("\n \t STACK UNDERFLOW");
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("\n The top most element is %s", a[top]);
    return a[top];
}
```

Here is an example run:

```
----------------------------------------
         ARRAY OF STACK 
----------------------------------------
 [1] PUSH
 [2] POP
 [3] PEEK
 [4] DISPLAY
 [5] EXIT
----------------------------------------
 Enter you Choice: 1
----------------------------------------
Enter element to add: test

----------------------------------------
         ARRAY OF STACK 
----------------------------------------
 [1] PUSH
 [2] POP
 [3] PEEK
 [4] DISPLAY
 [5] EXIT
----------------------------------------
 Enter you Choice: 3

 The top most element is test
```

`x` appears to be temporary variable that should be local to the functions that require it.  In general it's a good idea to eliminate global variables.  Create a struct to hold stack state, and pass a pointer to that struct to each function.  Consider separating the UI from functions that does stuff.  In this case, move the `printf()` to `main()`.  This allows you to easily reuse your functions.  For instance, pop() could be written as `char *data = peek(); if(data) top--; return data;`.  Check the return value from `scanf()` otherwise you may be dealing with undefined data.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("\n The top most element is: ");
            strcpy(x,a[top]);
            printf("%s",x);
```